# Randomize order of questions

Tags: javascript, python, html, mechanicalturk

I am creating a voice naturalness test in MTurk, using the template provided. It populates `${audio_url}` from a provided csv. However, it will always present the questions in the same order as the rows of the csv.

Is there a way to randomize this?

If I have to create it in python, that would be fine, if I could see an example. If there's a way to modify the javascript or html template to do this, that would be fine, as well.

Comment: Are you importing your questions into an array?

Comment: What do you mean? I know what an array is, but it’s just a csv file with a list of audio samples.

Comment: How is your app importing the data from the csv?

Comment: It’s just done through the MTurk html template. I don’t know how the backend works.